# From Your Organization is missing

Tags: sharepoint-addin

I am working on premise 2016 and followed all steps required for adding a Provider Hosted Add-In and my Add-In is visible on App Catalog Site. If I click on "add an app" on my app catalog site then I can see my application under "From Your Organization" section.

[image]

But when I navigate to another web application I do not see this option. Am I missing something here?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each web application, you can only have one App Catalog. You have to repeat the same steps you followed for adding a Provider Hosted Add-In in the second web application or other web applications.

Look at [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/3c66fd54-1385-4e3f-8233-1c053b98f006/multiple-app-catalogue-in-sp-13?forum=sharepointdevelopment).